# How to edit Kubernetes' deployment yml file dynamically?

Tags: python, linux, shell, yaml

I have the deployment.yml for Kubernetes. Now, I want to write a shell script to edit certain fields in the yml file dynamically, every time a new Docker image is generated with new name.

Is there any plugin or tool for this?

Comment: you can use circleCI for this, its a good tool. In the CI stage you can dynamically replace the build_Id of docker images placed in kubernetes deployment file and the scripts can be managed to connect to docker registry and kubernetes clusters

Comment: I need to use Jenkins, actually.